# Are QSql::Out and QSql::InOut used outside of calling a store procedure?

Tags: mysql, qt

I am using Qt5 to access a MySQL database. It is easy to execute INSERT queries using QSqlQuery + prepare() + bindValue().

Now I noticed that bindValue() has an optional paramType parameter that can be set to QSql::Out and QSql::InOut.

Is it correct that the QSql::Out and QSql::InOut arguments are useful when CALLing procedures and that they have no use for lets say a SELECT statement? Are there other use cases than CALL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that QSql::Out and QSql::InOut are actually intended for use with procedure calls only.

However it also turned out that Qt/MySQL parameter binding does not support the mentioned OUT and INOUT parameters types (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448906/calling-server-stored-procedure-using-binding)).